# Assembly for MSP430 doesn't work

Tags: c++, msp430

I'm currently learning assembly with MSP430.
This simple code should trigger an interrupt for TimerA.

```
#include "msp430.h"                     ; #define controlled include file

RSEG CSTACK

RSEG CODE

  Reset: 
    mov.w #WDTPW|WDTHOLD, &WDTCTL ; stop watchdog
    mov.w #MC_0|TACLR, &TACTL; stop timer
    mov.w #7D0h, &TACCR0; count to 2000
    mov.w #CCIE ,&TACCTL0
    mov.w #MC_1|TAIE|TASSEL_2, &TACTL; RESET timerA, start it and set clock to VCO
    mov.b #BIT0, &P2DIR; output
    mov.b #BIT0, &P2OUT;
  Main: 
    mov.w #GIE, SR;
    jmp Main;
  INTER:
      xor.b #BIT0, &P1OUT ; toggle LED
      reti

  RSEG RESET
   DW Reset;

 ORG 0xFFF2; address of interrupt
      DW INTER                     
  END
```

But get following error after trying to load code on my MSP:

```
Error[e104]: Failed to fit all segments into specified ranges. Problem 
discovered in segment CODE. Unable to place 1 block(s) (0xfff4 byte(s) total)
in 0x7e0 byte(s) of memory.
The problem occurred while processing the segment placement command
"-P(CODE)CODE=F800-FFDF", where at the moment of placement the  
available memory ranges were "CODE:f800-ffdf" 
Error while running Linker
```

I am sure it is some noob error, but can you explain what it is?

Comment: It seems to think you want to place just shy of 64 KiB of code into about 2 KiB of memory (if my mental arithmetic on 0xFFF4 and 0x07E0 are correct).  What you need to do to fix that, I've no idea, but it is probably related to the `ORG 0xFFF2` line.

Comment: Open your linker command file (named `lnk430f5438a.xcl` or something similar), and check your CODE segment definitions (there should be a few of them in there).

Comment: ehm, i though ORG 0xfff2 i jusst  interrupt vector...